# C# Complex Linq- how to get objects whose ids or children's ids match

Tags: c#, linq

Let us say I have the following structure,

```
public class Parent
{
 public string Id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public List<Child> Children{get;set;}
}

public class Child{
 public string Id{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

and I have a list of string that contains Ids `List<string>Ids`, and list of Parents `List<Parent> parents`.
How can I filter parents to get only the following:

- A Parent whose Id is contained in ids along with all children.
- Only a Child whose Id is contained in ids along with its Parent.

So if ids contains a Parent id, I want it with children, and if it contains a Child id, I want it with its Parent (without the rest of children).

I tried the following, and it is working, the only issue is that if both parent Id and a child Id exists, it returns parent with only one child while it should return all children.

```
parents
  .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id) ||  
              p.Children.Any(x=>ids.Contains(x.Id)))
  .Select(res => new Parent() {  
     Name     = res.Name,
     Id       = res.Id,
     Children = es.Children
       .Where(child => ids.Contains(child.Id))
       .ToList()
   });
```

Comment: Any reason why you want it in a single line? It seems to me you have multiple conditions so why not first check the parents, and handle that case, and when it doesn't have the parent, handle the children scenario :) Readability of such a single line is well, not very high, and you seem to handle 2 different cases

Comment: Thank you for the insight, Knowledge of how to do it is one of the reasons, another reason is team related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite ugly, but shall work with your cases.

```
var result = parents
            .Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id) || p.Children.Any(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)))
            .Select(res => new Parent() 
                { Name = res.Name, 
                  Id = res.Id, 
                  Children =  res.Children.Any(c => ids.Contains(c.Id)) && !ids.Contains(res.Id) 
                                                ? res.Children.Where(child => ids.Contains(child.Id)).ToList() 
                                                : res.Children.ToList() })
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following using a dictionary may be more efficient

```
           string[] ids = parents.Select(x => x.Children.Select(y => y.Id)).SelectMany(x => x).OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToArray();

            Dictionary<string, List<Parent>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Parent>>();

            foreach (string id in ids)
            {
                List<Parent> parentId = parents.Where(x => x.Children.Any(y => y.Id == id)).ToList();
                dict.Add(id, parentId);
            }
```